# Will these tires fit on my bike?

Tags: tire, shimano, compatibility

If I were to purchase the “Aluminum Road Bike Commuter Bike Shimano 21 Speed 700c”, would I be able to remove the tires that the bike originally came with, and replace them with some “Michelin Lithium 2 Road Bike Tyres”? Links for the bike and the wheels are below. And if so, should I get the 23c or 25c? I’m riding on city streets and sidewalks.

[Original bike and its tyres](https://roadbikecity.com/bikes/road-bike/aluminum-road-bike-commuter-bike-shimano-21-speed-700c.html)

[New tyres on CRC website](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/mobile/us/en/michelin-lithion-2-road-bike-tyre/rp-prod48128?gs=1&sku=sku169662&pgrid=53546199518&ptaid=pla-423990859585)

Comment: What tire width does your bike currently have? If it is 25 mm, then another 25 mm tyres most probably fit. Try looking at the labels on the tyres, or just measure them with a caliper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers - yes they will fit. Rim size is correct (700c or ISO 622mm), 25mm width is same as originally fitted to the bike so rim width and frame clearance is OK.

Kinda do have to ask why you would be changing the tires for an identically sized set on a new bike though.

Re the 23mm vs 25mm size. For casual riding wider tires with lower pressure will give you more comfort and grip, so I could not recommend the 23mm size. You might actually want to consider going up a size to 28mm.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your much appreciated help. I’m new to cycling, and this website helped a bunch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will fit. You should also be able to reuse the existing tubes without issue.

As to which width tires to get, that is completely up to you. In theory, the 23mm tires will offer less rolling resistance, although in practice this may not be true. The 25mm tires will offer somewhat more grip while braking & cornering.